# Taking notes with filename input not working html?

Tags: php, forms

I have added a simple not taking page to my website, which takes in user input of filename and the notedata.

However whenever I run the code the code I just get a bunch of errors and some non-working code:

HTML form:

```
<form method="post">
    <div style="margin-right:">
      <input type="text" class="fileName" name="fileName" id="fileName" size="35"><br>
      <textarea type="text" name="notes" id="notes"></textarea><br>
      <input type="Submit" name="Submit" value="Save">
    </div>
</form>
```

PHP form:

```
$noteName = $_POST['fileName'];
(line 51:)$noteData = $_POST['notes'];

(line 53:)$notes = fopen('' + $noteName,"wb");
fwrite($notes,$noteData);
fclose($notes);
```

Error list:

Notice: Undefined index: notes in C:\xampp\htdocs\NNDbase.php on line 51

Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in C:\xampp\htdocs\NNDbase.php on line 53

Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in C:\xampp\htdocs\NNDbase.php on line 53

Comment: do you have any check for `POST`-ing around these lines, like `if(!empty($_POST['filename']))`?

Comment: If you have both of those code snippets in the same file, then you need to check if there actually was any POST data first. Because the first request, that you make to get your form displayed initially, will be a GET request, so of course no POST data.

Answer (score -1):

> Try this

```
 if($_POST){
    $noteName = $_POST['fileName'];
    $noteData = $_POST['notes'];
    $notes = fopen('' + $noteName,"wb");
    fwrite($notes,$noteData);
    fclose($notes);
}
```